# Can any natural process explain this rate of CO2 increase?

Tags: climate-change, paleoclimatology

**Can any natural process explain this rate of CO2 increase?**

[![1000 years of CO2][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO0mK.png

The prior similar question used different data as its basis.
This version of the question is much easier to understand.

Comment: There are a few volcanoes in  Hawaii,so it seems possible that Hawaiian air is richer in CO2 than most other places. This is not to deny that industrial emissions also play a part.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/blogs/climateqa/mauna-loa-co2-record/

Comment: @Michael Walsby: If CO2 from Hawai'ian volcanos was a factor in the Keeling curve, you would see a correlation between volcanic activity and measured CO2, but instead you see a steady increase (with a small but consistent annual variation due to seasonal changes), with no corresponding increase in volcanic activity.

Comment: @jamesqf They have to skip some readings when the volcano is active. When the volcano is inactive they compare these readings with readings from all over the globe and they are validated.